# Add CSS only when a section or is in range

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parallax, sticky

I am trying to make a "sticky" image where all images of class ".img" add a css attribute and then remove it when it is not in range.

I do this by getting the ID of each of the images and pass it to a function that makes it fixed (addCSS). It works fine - the images stick right where they are supposed to smoothly, but when I try to scroll up, they keep their css. I want to remove the CSS property when the wScroll is outside the range.

```
$('.img').each(function () {
        var sectionOffset = $(this).offset().top;
        var attID = $(this).attr('id');attID = $("#"+attID.toString()+"");
        if (wScroll >= sectionOffset && wScroll <= (sectionOffset + sectionHeight)) {
            addCSS(attID);
        }
    });
function addCSS(element) {
        element.css({
            'position': 'fixed',
            'top': stickyPosition - 75,
            'left': OffsetLeft
        });
    }
function removeCSS(element) {
        element.css({
            'position': '',
            'top': '',
            'left': ''
        });
}
```

I tried modifying it this way but it makes it jump :(

```
$('.img').each(function () {
        var sectionOffset = $(this).offset().top;
        var attID = $(this).attr('id');attID = $("#"+attID.toString()+"");
        if (wScroll >= sectionOffset && wScroll <= (sectionOffset + sectionHeight)) {
            addCSS(attID);
        }
        else if (wScroll > (sectionOffset + sectionHeight) || wScroll < sectionOffset) {
            removeCSS(attID);
        }
    });
```

I managed to get it working smoothly without using an array, but the code is a bit long and I was hoping to simplify it without losing function.

Here is a simplified version: http://codepen.io/ebevers/pen/xwbdbP
for this, I just need the squares to jump back into place. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
// Last section and current section
var last_section = -1;
var current_section = -1;

// Scroll
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){

    // Get current section
    for (var i = 0; i < jQuery('.row').length; i++) {
        if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() >= jQuery('.row:eq('+i+')').position().top) {
            current_section = i;
        }
    }

    // If change
    if (current_section != last_section) {
        removeCSS(jQuery('.row:eq('+last_section+') .img'));
        addCSS(jQuery('.row:eq('+current_section+') .img'));
        last_section = current_section;
    }

});
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/c4z9satw/**

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it, but without globals and it relies on explicitly set identifiers.

Added CSS:

```
.active {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var rows = $(".row");

  $(".img").each(function() {
    var row = false, i, l, id;

    for (i = 0, l = rows.length; i < l; i++) {
      id = "#" + this.id.toString();

      if ($(rows[i]).find(id)[0] != undefined) {
        row = rows[i];
        break;
      }
    }

    if (!row)
      return false;

    if ((window.scrollY >= $(row).offset().top) && (window.scrollY < $(row).offset().top + $(row).outerHeight()))
      $(this).addClass("active");
    else
      $(this).removeClass("active");
  });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w7ru130s/2/